# update plot output on multiple checkbox input

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

//server.r

```
library(RJDBC)
    library(dplyr)
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(scales)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(gridExtra)
library(DT)
library(ggthemes)
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
library(shinyWidgets)
dsn_driver = ""
dsn_database = ""            # e.g. "BLUDB"
dsn_hostname = "" # e.g.: "awh-yp-small03.services.dal.bluemix.net"
dsn_port = ""                # e.g. "50000"
dsn_protocol = ""            # i.e. "TCPIP"
dsn_uid = ""        # e.g. "dash104434"
dsn_pwd = ""

jcc = JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", "db2jcc4.jar");
    jdbc_path = paste("jdbc:db2://",  dsn_hostname, ":", dsn_port, "/", dsn_database, sep="");
    conn = dbConnect(jcc, jdbc_path, user=dsn_uid, password=dsn_pwd)
    query ="select RETAIL_STORE_AREA_WISE.STORE_NM as ST,RETAIL_STORE_AREA_WISE.TOWN_NAME as TOWN_NAME,RETAIL_STORE_AREA_WISE.AREA_NAME as AR,
    ROUND(SUM(RETAIL_STR_SALES_MASTER.GRAND_TOTAL),2) as SALES_VALUE
    from retail_str_sales_master, retail_store_area_wise
    where retail_store_area_wise.store_id = retail_str_sales_master.store_id
    GROUP  BY
    RETAIL_STORE_AREA_WISE.STORE_NM ,
    retail_store_area_wise.area_name,
    retail_store_area_wise.area_code,
    retail_store_area_wise.town_name
    ORDER BY RETAIL_STORE_AREA_WISE.STORE_NM,
    retail_store_area_wise.area_name"
    query1=dbGetQuery(conn,query)    

    #Dropdown Function 



    biz = data.frame(



    Are=query1$AR,
    TOWNNAME=query1$TOWN_N,
    Storename=query1$ST,
    Salevalue=query1$SALES_VALUE,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )


    # connection with dash db
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
      autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(50000, session)
      output$Box1 = renderUI(selectInput("yr",label = "select a Area NAME",c(unique(isolate(biz$Are)),"pick one"),"pick one"))

      output$Box2 = renderUI(

        if (is.null(input$yr) || input$yr == "pick one"){return()
        }else checkboxGroupInput("sector", 
                          "Select a Town_Name", 
                          choices = c(unique(biz$TOWNNAME[which(biz$Are == input$yr)])),
                          "pick one")
      )  



      subdata1 = reactive(biz[which(biz$TOWNNAME== input$sector),])

      output$text1 <- renderText({
        autoInvalidate()
        sprintf("Total value  of store per day", input$sector,"sales")
      })
      output$text2 <- renderText({
        autoInvalidate()
        sprintf("Total Number of bills per day", input$sector,"sales")

      })
      output$view = DT::renderDataTable({
        autoInvalidate()
        if(is.null(input$sector) ){return()
        } else if (input$sector == "pick one"){return()

        } else 
        {
          autoInvalidate()

          subdata1()[,c("TOWNNAME","Storename","Salevalue")]



        }
      },rownames = FALSE,class = 'cell-border stripe')
```

not able to generate output on multiple select input it is working well on one select input but not in multiple select

```
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    autoInvalidate()
    if (is.null(input$sector)){return()
    } else if(input$sector == "pick one") { return()
    } else p <- ggplot(data=subdata1() ,aes(x =Storename, y = Salevalue,group=Storename),environment=environment())+ geom_histogram(stat = "identity",fill = "blue")+ 

        geom_smooth() + ggtitle("ggplot")   

    print(p + theme(axis.text.x =
                      element_text(size  = 10,angle = 45,hjust = 1,vjust = 1)))    })

})
```

//ui.r

```
library(RJDBC)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(shinydashboard)
library(gridExtra)
library(DT)
library(ggthemes)
library(plotly)
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "STORE ANALYTICS"),
  dashboardSidebar(

    sidebarMenu(menuItem("Per Day Sales", tabName = "root", icon = icon("calendar"),uiOutput("Box1"),
      uiOutput("Box2")

    ))
  ),
  dashboardBody(

    fluidPage(


      fluidRow(

        box(
          width = 20, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
          title = textOutput("text1"),
          plotlyOutput(paste('plot'))),




        box(

          width = 8, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
          title = "STORE SALES PER MONTH ",
          dataTableOutput("view")

           )

      )

    )  

  )
)
```

Comment: help me out with this code i am still stuck in this code

Comment: Are you sure your data ```output$view``` works well with multiple selection?

Comment: yes it is working but not showing the exact data with multiple select